# Which registrar checks the most domains?

Tags: domains

When I want a new domain, I usually use GoDaddy to check, and another registrar to register. This is because GoDaddy check my wanted domain against the most TLD's.

Are there any other sites/registrars that checks against more TLD's?

What I want is to type my wanted second-level domain.. Ex: bobsplace. And then it searches through bobsplace.com bobsplace.net bobsplace.me etc, and reports back to me which is availible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** You are looking for something like [this](http://www.w3tool.com/domain/).

Comment: Well, no. What I want is to type my wanted second-level domain.. Ex: bobsplace. And then it searches through bobsplace.com bobsplace.net bobsplace.me etc, and reports back to me which is availible or not.

Comment: Correct. If you would edit your answer to contain this info I will give you the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

All registrars check against the master database.  Assuming they're halfway competent (and they basically are) there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.101domain.com/ - This is one of the most comprehensive domain registrycheckers featuring 1113 Domain Name Extensions!! You can Search All Top Extensions from:  Asian Domains  African Domains  European Domains  North American Domains  Central American Domains  South American Domains and Oceanian Domains.